# one c++ syntax question

Tags: c++, syntax

Sorry if the question is silly. I come from java background.

In the following code, base_list is a parent class of SqlAloc, but what's the meaning of public memory?

```
class base_list :public memory::SqlAlloc  
{  
protected:  
  list_node *first,**last;  
  uint32_t elements;  
public:
};
```

Comment: Please remove the **, I spent 5 minutes trying to understand what they were.

Comment: removed, I wanted to highlight it, but looks like it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Memory` is probably a *namespace* (kind of like an outer class) in which `SqlAlloc` is defined.

C++ has both `public` and `private` inheritance (`protected`, too, actually.) `public` inheritance is just like Java inheritance; in `private` inheritance, though, code outside the derived class doesn't know about the base class. It's a way to inherit implementation without inheriting type. In Java, you can only do both.

Comment: a namespace is not "kind of like an "outer class". Far from it. Its syntactic sugar, not a construct of the language. (and you forgot `virtual` inheritance)

Comment: If in Java I define a class A empty except for static inner classes B, C, and D, there are no *meaningful* differences between A and a C++ namespace, from the perspective of B, C, and D. The class names B, C, and D are scoped inside A, and that's about it. You can come up with little corner cases where the comparison falls down, but that hardly spoils my *kind of like an*.

Comment: I always thought that C++ namespaces are kind of like Java packages - but I guess that's just me...

Comment: Yeah, a package is a good analogy too, although packages don't contain functions the way  namespaces can. Pick your poison.

Comment: I checked the code, memory is really a namespace. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ernest: this is a C++ question, bad analogies will only confuse the OP. Classes have constructors, instances, members. Namespaces are just *syntactic sugar*, a label you can place before an identifier to prevent name clashes. Sure the scope resolution operator `::` is the same, but really, classes and namespaces are not the same thing, not by a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

`memory` is either a namespace or a class (struct). `public` means that all member functions and member data which were declared in `SqlAlloc` class(struct) as public and protected will be visible in `base_list` as public and protected.

Answer (score 0):

`base_list` is *publicly* deriving from `SqlAlloc` which is either a namespace-class, or nested-class, depending upon what `memory` is -  which could be either a *namespace* or a *class*.